# Lua | Count Occurences of Each Item in a Table

Tags: lua, lua-table

hi I'm trying to convert this python code to Lua

```
names=['Deepak','Reema','John','Deepak','Munna','Reema','Deepak','Amit','John','Reema']
d={}
for i in range(len(names)-1):
    x=names[i]
    c=0
    for j in range(i,len(names)):
        if names[j]==names[i]:
            c=c+1
    count=dict({x:c})
    if x not in d.keys():
        d.update(count)
print (d)
```

I got all the other parts working from top but I couldn't figure out how to convert this part into Lua

```
    if x not in d.keys():
        d.update(count)
```

would be really great if someone can help me make sense of this conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
  if x not in d.keys():
        d.update(count)
```

`x` is the name currently indexed in that loop cycle

`d` is a dictionary that is used to store the count of each name

`c` is a dictionary with a single entry, the count `c` of `x` in `names`

So that line basically says:

if the current name `x` has not been counted yet (is not in our dictionary), add its count `c` to `d` using the name in `x` as key.

This code is not very efficient as it counts the names every time, even if that name has already been counted. The order should be changed so you only count if there is no count in `d`, yet.

There is also no need to iterate over the whole array for each entry. That nested loop is nonsense. You can count that in one go.

You shouldn't learn from whatever resource that is.

In Lua the snippet above would look something like:

```
if not d[x] then d[x] = c end
```

or simply

```
d[x] = d[x] or c
```

This is how you could implement it in Lua efficiently.

```
local names= {'Deepak','Reema','John','Deepak','Munna','Reema','Deepak',
  'Amit','John','Reema'}
local counts = {}    
for _, v in ipairs(names) do
  counts[v] = counts[v] and counts[v] + 1 or 1
end
```